# A good synonym for hiding someone's neck

Tags: word-request, verbs, phrases

When it's cold outside or when you are in shame, someone might hide their neck as if a tortoise retracting it to its shell, but what verb or expression can I use to describe to action.

> Ex: When the wind picked up outside, he crossed his arms and ... his neck.

Answer (score 2):

A couple verbs are possible in this context: "sink", "dip", "retract", etc. However, in general, in English this is described as a movement of the head as opposed to the neck.

A person may *sink* his head or *dip* his head (into his coat/collar) when the chill in the air hits. You could say "sink/dip one's neck", but they are less natural-sounding.

It's also possible to say: "He *retracted* his neck in the chill." "Retract" here is opposite in meaning to "crane one's neck".